# load method vs getCollection method which is better and faster

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model

Let assume we have 1 record in database and id is 1

we can get record using 2 method load by id and getCollection.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('stackexchange/questions')
             ->getCollection()
             ->addFieldToFilter('id',1);
foreach($model as $mod) {
    echo $mod->getName();
}
```

**OR**

```
$model = Mage::getModel('stackexchange/questions')
             ->getCollection()
             ->getFirstItem();
echo $model->getName();
```

and we can get single records using load();

```
$model = Mage::getModel('stackexchange/questions')->load(1);
echo $model->getName();
```

Here is my question. 
Which method is faster and better to use and why ?

If none of then which is the fastest way to access data ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you need.
If you plan to call `save` on one of the objects (specially if it's an EAV entity) you should use `load`.
If you just need to display some data you should use the collection approach.
But be careful with `getFirstItem`. It loads the collection completely.
If you only need one single item you should use `getFirstItem()` in combination with a limit `->setPageSize(1)->setCurPage(1)`.

Also, there are some cases when you absolutely need to use `load`. Some events are dispatched when calling `load` (like `afterLoad`) and others are dispatched when loading a collection.
You might have logic that depends on these events.

Comment: Good one, I'm late to the party ^^ interesting, are you sure `setCurPage(1)` is required ?

Comment: not sure if it's required, but it's safe to add it. You don't know where your collection has been.

Comment: so we can say that `setCurPage(1)` is a condom for collections

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to access the name (without updating the entity) using collection is definitely faster but you need to limit it by using `setPageSize(1)`:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('stackexchange/questions_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('name')
    ->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
     $name = $collection->getFirstItem()->getName();
}
```

Comment: Mage::getResourceModel('stackexchange/questions_collection') is resourceModel load data faster then model ?  how ?

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara no I prefer using `Mage::getResourceModel('stackexchange/questions_collection')` than `Mage::getModel('stackexchange/questions')->getCollection()` but they are the same

Answer (score 1):

both have different purpose

`load($id)` we normally use when we have to update or delete that record.

`getCollection()` use for getting number of records.

But In My opinion if you want only one data then instead of `getCollection` `load` is the best to use.

But if you want Multiplet  data then you have to use `getCollection`.

At the end of this if you want to see query. then `echo $model->getSelect();`

Comment: let's assume I need 2 order details and Ids are 20 and 21 so what should I do. get collection and filter by id or load by this 2 Ids two-time

Comment: If its two ercord then do `getCollection` with filter of id 20 and 21